# How to fix "Can't update table testtab in stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a table

```
CREATE TABLE testtab (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `food_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Table contains below  row

```
INSERT INTO testtab (`customer_id`, `food_id`, `created_date`)
    VALUES ('433', '9', '2019-05-14 12:00:54');
```

Now the condition is  for a specific customer_id there can be only one row with food_id either 8 or 9.

Now I try to add the below insert statement

```
INSERT INTO testtab (`customer_id`, `food_id`, `created_date`)
    VALUES ('433', '8', '2019-05-14 12:00:54');
```

Now It should either  get failed  or  get deleted immediately after inserted(record with tag_id=8).I have used the below trigger.But unfortunately i got error

Can't update table 'testtab' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `ipay`$$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `testtabTrigger`$$

CREATE

    TRIGGER `testtabTrigger` AFTER INSERT ON `testtab` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM testtab WHERE food_id =9 AND customer_id = new.customer_id) =1 && new.food_id = 8) THEN
    DELETE FROM testtab WHERE food_id = 8 AND customer_id = new.customer_id;
    END IF;


END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: use a before insert trigger, and raise exception

Comment: IN your example would a food_id = 10 be ok in the second insert?

Comment: Hi Salmon,Answer is no.As there is condition  only between 8 and 9.Once record with id =9 is present and i try to add food_id =8  it should not be inserted.For food_id =10 it should blindly  get inserted

Comment: Tried with before insert trigger  also and exception is same

Comment: IF this is a MYSQL question the error tells you what you need to know.AND in a before insert trigger the base has not been written to yet so you have the opportunity to throw an error to stop the insert being written.You also have the opportunity to amend NEW. values (although I don't think this appropriate in your case).

Comment: A trigger is not allowed to modify the same table it's triggering on.

Comment: `SQL Server` isn't `MySQL`. Don't mix up the tags, you'll only annoy people that came for one tag and found something else. *Read* the tag descriptions before you use them

Comment: If this cannot be done by trigger,then  is there any other way??

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that you do something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `testtabTrigger` BEORE INSERT ON `testtab` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (EXISTS (SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM testtab tt
                WHERE tt.food_id = 9 AND
                      tt.customer_id = new.customer_id
               ) AND
         new.food_id = 8
        ) THEN
          signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'Attempted insert of 8 when there is a 9';
    END IF;
END;
```